# Is it proper to use 'be destined to' to mean fate?

Tags: idioms

As this [essay](https://grammar.yourdictionary.com/vs/difference-between-fate-and-destiny-meaning-and-use.html) points out, fate is things that will eventually happen, regardless of one's endeavour, while destiny is something that comes as a result of one's choices or efforts.

Since the word 'destined' is the adjective of 'destiny', I doubt it's suitable to use 'be destined to' to convey the idea of something totally out of one's control, i.e., fate.

Is it proper to use 'be destined to' to mean fate? If it is not, what are the suitable idioms?

Postscript: I remembered once reading the expression 'there's some fate in it' in a simplified version of the novel [*Treasure Island*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treasure_Island). Maybe it suits the idea of fate, I guess, at least literally.

Comment: We commonly say that someone or something _was destined to_ become something else, meaning that we now know that that was what _did_ eventually happen to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OED gives as sense 1a of ***destiny*** the following meaning:

> That which is destined or fated to happen; predetermined events
> collectively;

In all the more prominent senses of *destiny* the OED includes the word *fate*.

But the words are used differently, I would agree - with *fate* more associated with serious philosophical thought, and *destiny* being more conversational - and hence, perhaps, used more loosely.

Comment: Some 'difference between' web sites, accessible using a Google search like 'XXX YYY difference', parrot a notion that a person's 'fate' is an eventual outcome that was preordained (whatever that means) whereas their destiny is one that they have brought about by decisions or efforts. I do not like these 'difference' sites, and personally consider 'fate' and 'destiny' as you state here. I can imagine saying 'Although the nine-year-old Abraham Lincoln did not know it, his destiny was to become President and be shot at a theatre'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Hitler begins *Mein Kampf* with the German word *Schicksal* in the first sentence. "Destiny" had evidently decreed that he should have been born at Braunau-am-Inn, on the German/Austrian border - as he - presumably some sort of messiah- would unite the two great German Reichs. I've no experience of German, and the exact sense of the word *Schicksal* but my guess is, however, that even he was writing only loosely - and conversationally.

Comment: My take, as very much a German beginner, is that _Schicksal_ happens to you and you can't change it; often a negative thing like a terminal illness. You discover it rather than decide it. Contrast with _Bestimmung_, which I think applies when you or someone else believes that you are meant to do/to be something like become the _Führer_. You can't avoid _Schicksal_ but you can avoid _Bestimmung_. I am not enough of a Hitler scholar to comment on his usage.

Comment: Except to say that using _Schicksal_ suggests that Hitler believed that history, or Destiny, or Wotan, or someone or something, had decided that he _would_ be Führer.

Answer (score -1):

I would generally expect "destined to be" rather than "be destined to".

Comment: You're just looking at different parts of the same sentence: "*I am **destined to be** free*" vs. "*I **am destined to** be free*". They're not different expressions